# Using _c before get in javascript map

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Say I have a map

```
let map = new Map();
let newMap = {...map};
```

`newMap.get(key)` doesn't work for me, I have to do `newMap._c.get(key)`

Has anyone come across this problem before?

Comment: let newMap = new Map(map);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{...foo}` is an object spread. It will copy all enumerable properties from an object, just like doing `Object.assign({}, foo)`.

The issue is that a `Map`'s key/values pairs are not properties, they are stores inside an opaque data structure inside the map. `...` will not work to copy a Map because it doesn't access Map data. The reason you are seeing `_c` is because that is the private data structure used by your Map polyfill to implement the private internal data structure.

To copy a Map, you can use the `Map` constructor, which takes an iterable as its argument, and since `Map` instances are iterable, you can simply do

```
var newMap = new Map(map);
```